# NFC: Spotify URIs open app, not specified resource

Tags: nfc, intents, spotify, url

My goal is to program NFC tags in such a way, that Spotify starts playing a specific track/album/playlist.

But after writing a Spotify URI (e.g. `spotify:track:6rqhFgbbKwnb9MLmUQDhG6`) to my tag, it only opens the app and disregards the resource.

The problem seems to be the way Android handles the tag, because the URI works without any problems when I call it from another app.

A related problem is the way URLs are handled: When I open a Spotify URL like `https://open.spotify.com/track/6rqhFgbbKwnb9MLmUQDhG6` from another app, it directly launches Spotify, whereas it would unsuccessfully try to open it with a browser after touching the tag.

It seems like Android only processes the scheme of the URI. Is this correct? If so, is there something that can be done to circumvent this? Why would that be the case?